# How to implement callback listener in BroadcastReceiver onReceive on notification tap?

Tags: android, callback, broadcastreceiver, listener, android-notifications

I am creating an app that sends a notification when an SMS is received. When the notification is tapped, it opens the MainActivity and shows the received SMS. The problem is, when the app is closed and an SMS is received, the mListener inside the onReceive method of BroadcastReceiver class produces a null pointer exception (NPE). Logs show the error: "Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.smsread.listener.SmsListener.messageReceived(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference".

What can I do so that the control can be passed to the activity from onReceive?

I can perform the action sending notification within the onReceive but doesn't seem appropriate. I wish to pass the message to the interface and let the activity implement it.

SmsReceiver.java

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    //interface
    private static SmsListener mListener;

    public static void bindListener(SmsListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        Object[] pdus = new Object[0];
        if (bundle != null) {
            pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        }
        StringBuilder messageBody = new StringBuilder();

        if (pdus != null) {
            for (Object pdus1 : pdus) {
                SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus1);

                messageBody.append(smsMessage.getMessageBody());
            }
        }
        //Pass the message text to interface
        mListener.messageReceived(messageBody.toString());    // mListener here is null
    }
}
```

I expect the mListener to pass the control to the MainActivity where the interface is implemented but mListener is found to be null. Please help as to what changes have to be done so that mListener points to the MainActivity.

If there is a better way to implement the scenario I wish to implement, suggestions are more than welcome.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is your activity running when the broadcast is received?

Comment: No. As I said, the app is closed. So mListener is bound to be null. So how should I implement the code that my purpose is achieved?

Comment: is this code " mListener.messageReceived(messageBody.toString())"  produce  notification?

Comment: No. The implementation of messageReceived in MainActivity handles the part of sending notification. Since my question is not concerned to that part, I haven't provided it. I only need help in solving this NPE of mListener or execute methods of MainActivity

Comment: according to your question  When the notification is tapped, it opens the MainActivity..... broadcast reciever is  called even app is killed isn't it ?  and you need to produce notification when broadcast is fired and produce notification from here and set pending intent to produce main activity  on click notification

Comment: Yes BroadcastReceiver is called even if the app is killed and onReceive is getting called. But since activity ceases to exist, mListener is null. If you can suggest a way so that MainActivity implementing the interface can be passed the control from onReceive, my problem will be solved. All of the work of showing notification and producing main activity on click of notification will executed then in the main activity.

Comment: @Rahul Why don't you send it in intent so the activity starts if it is not already started and handle the intent if it is already started?

Comment: "I can perform the action sending notification within the onReceive but doesn't seem appropriate." – Why not? `Notification`s aren't tied to `Activity` classes. All you need to post one is a `Context`. If you're concerned about having repetitive code, you can simply make a `static` helper method somewhere that takes a `Context`, and call that from your Receiver and wherever else you need.

Comment: @MikeM. Sounds cool. But here comes another doubt. I have a method createNotificationChannel which is called in activity's onCreate. createNotificationChannel method initializes my NotificationManager object. The same NotificationManager object is used in sendNotification method while sending notification using its notify method. But, when app is killed, the NotificationManager object becomes null. Hence throws an NPE when sendNotification is triggered. What can you suggest for this? How to retain the same notification manager used to create the notification channel and sending notification?

Comment: `NotificationManager` is a system service, and is another thing that can be obtained with just a `Context`. You don't need that same reference you used in `MainActivity` in creating your channels, to post `Notification`s elsewhere. No matter where in your app you obtain `NotificationManager`, it's going to be the same system service, with the same capabilities as anywhere else.

Comment: @MikeM. That was the thing I was looking for. Thank you so much. That solved my problem exactly the way I wanted it to. Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call function of an Activity that was already destroyed.

If you want to communicate with your activity from a BroadcastReceiver, Use Intent.

Create a new Intent with your Activity as target and send the message as as Extra in Intent Extras Bundle.

In your Activity, you can set `launchMode` to `singleInstance` or `singleTask` in your manifest file. This means that the Intent if sent and your Activity is already open, it will call `onIntent` function in your activity where you will call the listener function.

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

```
@Override
 public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    processDataFromBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Be sure to read about launch modes and `singleInstance` to fully understand what it means or you might get unexpected behavior:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack#ManifestForTasks

Comment: and what if the activity isn't open?

Comment: @Rahul it will be opened if it is not already open, and if it is already open then intent is passed in above function